# Purpose of CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast

Tags: core-bluetooth

When configuring CBMutableCharacteristic to setup an iOS device as a peripheral, one of the possible values for CBCharacteristicProperties is CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast.

But if you choose it, at run-time you'll get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast is not allowed'
```

I'm creating the characteristic this way:

```
let characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: myCharacteristicUUID,
                        properties: CBCharacteristicProperties.Broadcast,
                        value: characteristicValue,
                        permissions: CBAttributePermissions.Readable)
```

What is the purpose of `CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast`? `CBCharacteristicPropertyRead` and `CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify` work but I'd like to know why I can't use the other value.

Ideally, I'd like to broadcast user data as a peripheral without serving as a beacon. Is this feasible?

Comment: Note that if you specify the value when you create the characteristic you won't be able to change it. You need to specify nil for the initial value and then update it as required if you want to able to change the data.

Comment: Ah right - thanks. I realise that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBCharacteristicProperties) is pretty clear. You cannot use this property on characteristics you publish. The purpose of this value is to enable you to interpret the properties of characteristics that are discovered from other peripherals.

If you want to advise centralised that your value has changed then `notify` is the appropriate method.

Comment: So presumably these other peripherals are not iOS devices broadcasting their advertisements using CoreBluetooth?

Comment: That's right. Not everything in the Bluetooth 4.0 specification is available by Core Bluetooth